# How to check if an id points to a CGRect?

Tags: ios, struct, core-graphics, cgrect, kvc

Supposing we have:

```
id value = [self valueForKey:@"frame"];
BOOL valueIsCGRect = ???;
```

How can I decide? Should I cast id to something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The returned value will be of type `NSValue` for scalar types, which provides the method `objCType`, which returns the encoded type of the wrapped scalar type. You can use `@encode()` to get the encoding for an arbitrary type, and then compare the `objCType`.

```
if(strcmp([value objCType], @encode(CGRect)) == 0)
{
   // It's a CGRect
}
```

Comment: @Kevin Whoops, good catch, thanks! Though, after reading your answer, I'm not sure if my answer is even remotely correct... I think I totally misunderstood the question there.

Comment: I think you answered the question he asked, I just answered the problem and underlying misunderstanding.

Comment: That really seems the answer, though I cannot send objcType message to an id. Should I cast it before to... ...something?

Comment: @Geri You sure can, you just have to type it correctly, unlike me (it's `objCType`, not `objcType`, sorry). But, if you know that you will access the `frame` property and not arbitrary properties, you also know that it returns a `CGRect`, in which case @Kevin's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @JustSid Shouldn't you first verify that `value` is actually an `NSValue` object?

Comment: @rmaddy Yup, I just assumed that its already verified that there is an `NSValue` object at hand.

Comment: Yap. I missed it, just found objCType in NSValue documentation. It spells with capital "C" by the way. Thanks, answer just superfine.

Answer (score 4):

`CGRect` is a `struct`, not an Objective-C object, so if you have an `id`, you don't have a `CGRect`.

What you probably have is an `NSValue` wrapping a `CGRect`. You can get the `CGRect` out using [`[value CGRectValue]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

`frame` should certainly return a (wrapped) `CGRect`, but if you really need to check and make sure, you can use [JustSid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406649/900873).

Comment: It shows a NSRect actually, when I simply NSLog(@"%@", value), not NSValue.

Comment: @Geri That's because the returned value is actually of type `NSConcreteValue`, a subclass of `NSValue`. It still is an `NSValue`.

Comment: One question still remains - Once you know you have an `NSValue`, how do you know if the `NSValue` contains a `CGRect` or some other value? I think you need to look at the `NSValue objCType` but I don't know what it will equal for a `CGRect`.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit more context and some typecasting:

```
id value = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];

//Core Graphics types.
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
{
    //CGRect.
    if(strcmp([(NSValue*)value objCType], @encode(CGRect)) == 0)
    {
        //Get actual CGRect value.
        CGRect rectValue;
        [(NSValue*)value getValue:&rectValue];

        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rectValue));
    }

    //CGPoint.
    if(strcmp([(NSValue*)value objCType], @encode(CGPoint)) == 0)
    {
        //Get actual CGPoint value.
        CGPoint pointValue;
        [(NSValue*)value getValue:&pointValue];

        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(pointValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: NSValues aren't only used for CG types. Core Media and QTKit both use them as well.